# LoggingMessageFormatter with kafka-avro-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, avro, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to print avro messages on a kafka topic using kafka-avro-console-consumer in a log4j format.

For that I use the following kafka-avro-console-consumer command:

```
 bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic avro-test -property print.key=true --formatter kafka.tools.LoggingMessageFormatter
```

I have exported KAFKA_OPTS via the following command:

```
 export $KAFKA_OPTS= -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/file/kafka-console-consumer-log4j.properties
```

Now if I run regular kafka-console-consumer,using the following command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic avro-test -property print.key=true --formatter kafka.tools.LoggingMessageFormatter
```

I am able to produce a log4j enabled output:

```
[2018-07-17 19:09:40,514] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-10597] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-07-17 19:09:40,522] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-10597] Successfully joined group with generation 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-07-17 19:09:40,523] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-10597] Setting newly assigned partitions [avro-test-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-07-17 19:09:40,531] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-10597] Resetting offset for partition avro-test-0 to offset 23. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
```

However this formatting option does not kick in if I use a avro consumer using the following command:

```
 bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic avro-test -property print.key=true --formatter kafka.tools.LoggingMessageFormatter
```

It just resorts to a default formatter.

Is there something I may be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you override the `--formatter`, you won't get Avro messages anymore, as `kafka.tools.LoggingMessageFormatter` doesn't understand how to deserialize Avro

[Ref - source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer#L27-L35)

```
DEFAULT_AVRO_FORMATTER="--formatter io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter"

...

for OPTION in "$@"
do 
  case $OPTION in
    --formatter)
DEFAULT_AVRO_FORMATTER=""

...

exec $(dirname $0)/schema-registry-run-class kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer $DEFAULT_AVRO_FORMATTER ...
```

so, it should run `kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer --formatter kafka.tools.LoggingMessageFormatter`, as expected becuase the default is being unassigned, and `schema-registry-run-class` is defining `KAFKA_OPTS`, but you need to not have spaces or dollar signs on that line

```
export KAFKA_OPTS='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/file/kafka-console-consumer-log4j.properties'
bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer ...
```